# Capture a specific location of an image using OpenCV

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, tesseract

I am trying to organize my trading card collection digitally and am working on building a scanner using ocr to detect the names of my collection.

I need to use a webcam to snap a single image of each card in question. Snapping the image doesn't seem to be to difficult, but I need help determining how to get OpenCV to capture only a specific part of that image for OCR to work with. I'm trying to capture just the text portion of the image so that the artwork on the cards doesn't interfere with the OCR.

If my card will be placed in the same physical location each time, is there a way to get OpenCV to take an image and focus on just the area of the image that I'm interested in. 
Thank You

Sour Jack

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the problem. Do you want to use your OCR algorithm always on the same portion of the snapshot? If so, you can try something like:

```python
roi = img[y:y+height, x:x+width]
```

There is more information here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/29260/how-to-save-a-rectangular-roi/

Comment: Correct. That is exactly what I want to do. Each card in my collection has the title in a fixed location that is always in the same place.

Comment: All right. So you can use the numpy indexing to set your _region_ _of_ _interest_ as explained in the link (=